# What is Seven-Sided Strike's reach and damage division?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The Monk's [Seven-Sided Strike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/sevensided-strike) is a focus skill, a series of hits back and forth about a circle. Sometimes I'll see the Monk's animation reach enemies outside the circle. How far does this move reach, and how does it divide the 777% weapon damage over seven hits amongst the targets? If there is one target, does it get seven hits worth 111% weapon damage? Are some hits worth more than 111% (and others less)? If there are seven targets, does every one get a hit or are the hits chosen randomly within the circle (some receiving double, others receiving none)? Or do all targets in the area receive 777% weapon damage? Does the move prioritize enemies within the circle, and how many yards will the move reach if there is no one nearby?

[image: Seven-Sided Strike]

Answer (score 2):

Each hit does 111% weapon damage, and you hit 7 times.

I'm not positive, but I think each hit is randomly decided among available targets, so although unlikely, you can hit the same target 7 times even if other targets are available. If only 1 target is available, you will hit that target 7 times.

I haven't tested much with the range, so I don't think I can answer that part of your question very well, but if you use the ability on a regular basis you should get a good idea of the sort of range it will hit since there is an animation that shows you who you are hitting.

You do not have to be next to the target to hit them though, and I'm not even sure you need to be targetting anyone to use it. For example, one of the runes you unlock for the skill will teleport you to your target when you use that ability, so I have used it to target an enemy across the screen and teleport there.